# How could I join a smaller and a bigger div with rounded edges?

Tags: css, html

I currently have two divs on my site:

[image: current]

Notice that both have border [same color as the div] and they also have border radius.

I want to achieve this:

[image]

So I want them to join. How can I make this happen? If I can do it, is pure CSS and HTML enough or do I need jQuery and JS as well?

I though of making one large div of the two and then just setting a background that is similar to the two being united, but this is a not perfect for me because I have another object immediately below div 2.

So how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the divs next to each other and remove the border-radius from the big div's top right corner and from the left side of the smaller one.

```
#big {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}

#small {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:gray;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jxMW9/ for a demo.

Comment: I actually like this better than mine - it's cleaner. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

One idea that immediately comes to mind is to give the second div

```
position: relative;
left: -40px; /* Or whatever */
```

That will move the smaller div to the left.

You can use the `z-index` property to decide whether the bigger div should overlap the smaller one, or the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

You can have this **html**

```
<div id="one"> </div>
<div id="two"> </div>
```

and this **css**

```
#one {
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
#two {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
   border-top-right-radius: 10px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Have a look on this demo link http://jsfiddle.net/nGVaa/

Answer (score 0):

Just define `float:left;` on the divs and add additional class to the ones that you want to merge

```
.merge {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -10px;  
}
```

Check out the results on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TG4BH/)